# install Exception device not found ANDROID

Tags: android, debugging, exception

After

- increasing the timeout period
- trying kill server and start server commands
- restarting avd
- recreating avd
- restarting the application
- restarting the system

---

I'm still getting :

```
Failed to install DataAttach.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
Launch canceled!
```

What can be done in this case?
I'm running this app on Emulator (Android version 4.0)

**Edit**
Apps doesn't have any issues as far as code is concerned. Still they are showing error about device not found exception.

Comment: is only your DataAttach.apk is failed to install or all apk in your emulator 4.0 is failed to install?

Comment: Any solution? Note that the application with correct code are also showing this exception but they are giving the output properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to be sorted out by manually installing the apk through adb command prompt.

After navigating to tools folder from comand prompt,use

```
adb install DataAttach.apk
```

(where *DataAttach* refers to package name, as in my case package name is DataAttach.apk)

Answer (score 9):

I was also getting the same error, but to my surprise the application was installed correctly and I could launch the application. I am sending this reply just to let you know guys if you want to check and see if your application was actually installed along with this error.

Comment: hmmm. Sometimes, Android do behaves strangely !

Comment: Right dear I have same behave

Answer (score 3):

Using Project->clean option before run solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through the all the trick mentioned here. But it was not successfull.

After that I restarted my device and everything started working. I dont know the exact error but this trick helped me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a real device (not emulator) then try uninstalling the existing .apk from the device then re-run.  This solved the error message for me.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning my project helped me to solve this problem.

```
Project->Clean->Run
```