# An android virtual device that failed to load. click 'details' to see the error

Tags: android, eclipse

I just installed the Android plugin in Eclipse. Created a new virtual device running on Android 4.0 API level 14 (Nexus S) but it wont emulate. I read on one post that I could move the android folder to another location so i did so and to no avail,it still wont emulate the android window will start and the 'ANDROID' text will load for days and days but does not go any further. (I usually just read but have never posted so forgive me for my format)
Examining the console this was the text available:

```
   [2013-04-01 20:35:42 - Android Test] ------------------------------
   [2013-04-01 20:35:42 - Android Test] Android Launch!
   [2013-04-01 20:35:42 - Android Test] adb is running normally.
   [2013-04-01 20:35:42 - Android Test] Performing com.theprogrammer.android.test.MainActivityMainActivity activity launch
   [2013-04-01 20:35:43 - Android Test] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Phone_IceCreamSandwich'
   [2013-04-01 20:35:43 - Android Test] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Phone_IceCreamSandwich'
   [2013-04-01 20:35:55 - Android Test] New emulator found: emulator-5554
   [2013-04-01 20:35:55 - Android Test] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
   [2013-04-01 20:37:12 - Android Test] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
   [2013-04-01 20:37:12 - Android Test] Uploading Android Test.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
   [2013-04-01 20:37:12 - Android Test] Installing Android Test.apk...
   [2013-04-01 20:38:13 - Android Test] Success!
   [2013-04-01 20:38:13 - Android Test] Failed to install Android Test.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
   [2013-04-01 20:38:13 - Android Test] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
   [2013-04-01 20:38:13 - Android Test] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: If you start the emulator by running your project, try to start the emulator without running your project. Also if the emulator really take more then 20 minutes, I would just try to create a new one and start over. Don't forget: You can keep the emulator running between project runs, that will save you a lot of time (at least once your issue is solved :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that patience is a virtue because the emulator will take time to boot up but it will eventually boot up just take note of the RAM size that u give it because it will actually take that from your physical memory.

**EDIT**
I would recommend using Genymotion as I have been using it ever since this error and it has worked quite fine for me. Migrating to another PC is also simple since you just move the virtual devices.

Comment: best alternative would also be to use genymotion...so much quicker

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things you could do in this scenario:

- Reinstall the ADT Android Eclipse Tools
- Clean the Project
- Try Manual Launch Mode in eclipse

Also, I've found these answers that may help you:

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267354/install-exception-device-not-found-android)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927102/apk-fails-to-install-on-android-4-0-emulator)

Take a look, see if it helps. Android is weird sometimes.