# AVD manager won't start on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have a fresh setup of ubuntu 14.04
I am using Eclipse Juno.
SDK is updated and all API's are installed.

When I tried to launch AVD manager, I get the error as shown in screenshot here.
I've gone through other similar questions on stackoverflow. But no help.

If someone knows solutions please suggest.

An Android Virtual device that failed to load.

[image]

Created a virtual device and it gives below error :

[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong here... Just create new AVD and you should be good to go

Comment: @AjayKulkarni I did that too. The progress bar comes up and goes till the end and then nothing...

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749711/an-android-virtual-device-that-failed-to-load-click-details-to-see-the-error

Comment: @AjayKulkarni I attached screenshot of what error I get after creating AVD

Comment: Oh... got it. `AVD` needs virtualization. Looks like it is disabled in `BIOS`. Check this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/564910/kvm-is-not-installed-on-this-machine-dev-kvm-is-missing

Comment: @AjayKulkarni had to enable it in bios. all started to work good. thanks

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, please accept that answer to close this question

Answer (score 0):

Please go to `BIOS`, enable `virtialisation technology`. Save the chances, login, create new AVD. You should be good to go :)